# where is the javaws.jar file for Java8 in Solaris Sparc OS?

Tags: java

javaws.jar file used to be located under 1.7.0_72/jre/lib, but after I installed Java 8, I could not find it in the corresponding 1.8.0_31/jre/lib.

I checked .gz file downloaded from Oracle and it does not contain the jar file either.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks,

Comment: try a search(find command) of the file from command line ?

Comment: thank you for your reply. Did a grep, and there is no javaws.jar under the whole directory.